# PowerShell v2 Remoting Protocol in Java

Tags: java, powershell, office365

I'm trying to use Java to create and send messages for remote powershell commands, running over ws-man.  The specific implementation is for Office365, but the issue I'm having is that I can't figure out how to create valid powershell commands by hand because the spec for the message format doesn't seem to match what actually needs to be sent:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd303832(v=PROT.10).aspx

Has anybody else run into this issue?  I need to make this work without .Net, but I'm not sure if it's actually possible at this point.

Answer (score 1):

This might be relevant, I've not tried it though, it's a Java ws-man client provided by Intel:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/download-the-latest-intel-ws-management-java-client-library/

At the least, it has source code you can look at to see how it's done.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on WS-Man, but I did run across this article on launch PowerShell commands with a non-Windows client.  I think it will be helpful to you.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wmi/archive/2011/01/25/using-ws-man-to-invoke-a-powershell-cmdlet.aspx